# Loop through object with unkown levels of children in Preact

Tags: preact

I'm trying to loop through an object with children, that can have children, that can have children.

Basically I won't know how many child elements and levels the object can contain. Is there an easy way to loop through these, and render out a component in a list view without having to call the `Object.keys(myobject).map` many times in side eachother. Inside the render function?

```
parent: {
  term: "cats",
  children: {
    child: {
      term: "kids", 
      otherdata: "dekme", 
      children: {
        granddaughter: {term: "kids", otherdata: "dekme"},
        grandson: {term: "mip", some other data: "si"}
      }
   },


  }
}
```

And also the output should be something like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">child</a></li>
        <li><a href="">child</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">grandkid</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Great question! This class of problem is generally referred to as walking / tree walking, and there are probably some great libraries on npm that you could use to make it easier. We can write a simple recursive one by hand though.  I'll assume your nested objects containing child elements look something like this:

```js
var treeOfObjects = {
  children: [
    {
      name: 'billy'
    },
    {
      name: 'wanda',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'stanley'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Here's a walk function that will crawl that tree, call an `iterator` function you supply on each child it finds, and collect up the results in an Array.

```js
function walk(object, iterator, results) {
  // no results array it means we're at the root.
  // create the shared array, then map the root through our iterator.
  if (!results) {
    results = [iterator(object, null, object)];
  }

  if (object.children) {
    for (let i=0; i<object.children.length; i++) {
      // call the iterator on this child and append the result:
      let value = object.children[i];
      results.push(iterator(value, i, object));

      // now "walk into" the child object (appending its children, etc):
      walk(value, iterator, results);
    }
  }
  return results;
}
```

Here's what it looks like in practice:

```js
class Foo extends Component {
  render({ someTreeOfObjects }) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {walk(someTreeOfObjects, object => (
          <li>{object.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
// render(<Foo someTreeOfObjects={treeOfObjects} />)
// .. produces: 
// <ul>
//   <li>billy</li>
//   <li>wanda</li>
//   <li>stanley</li>
// </ul>
```

---

Update - for nested output:

```js
function nodeToListItem (object) {
  // if we have children, we'll recurse into them
  const children = object.children || [];
  return (
    <li>
      {object.name}
      {children.length>0 && (
        <ul>
          {children.map(nodeToListItem)}
        <ul>
      )}
    </li>
  );
}

class Foo extends Component {
  render({ someTreeOfObjects }) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {nodeToListItem(someTreeOfObjects)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Because the nesting from the original structure matches what we want to produce in the DOM, this ends up being a simple graph transformation.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I also need to add an ul for each level of children. I'll update the question with the structure of the data also.

Comment: Oh, that's easier! In these libraries you can actually pass a big nested array of children. I'll update my answer.